# Which of these methods is safe to export in a C++ dll?

Tags: c++, windows, dll

I'm making a dll to be used by several executables. I've read about the danger of using STL classes over the interface, I'm concerned about needing to compile with the same compiler and run with the same runtime.

Which of these signatures would be the right way to declare my methods, if the executables importing them might compile with different versions of the VC++ compiler and different versions of boost?

```
#include "boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time_types.hpp"

boost::posix_time::ptime getTime();
void setTime(boost::posix_time::ptime time);

time_t getTime();
void setTime(time_t time);

MyCustomTime getTime(); // Defined just like time_t
void setTime(MyCustomTime time);
```

Is there a better way to pass a date and time structure over a dll interface?

Answer (score 1):

Just pass what's convenient, and document what compiler/library is required. E.g. there's no guarantee that different compilers have the same `time_t`, and due to the overflow of UNIX 32 bits `time_t` in 2038 you can expect a switch to 64 bits `time_t` at some point. Obviously that breaks any DLL interface.